# Single Word Encompassing Utilities, Insurance and other Important Services

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to create a custom email address that will aggregate emails sent from utility companies, insurance companies and so forth (electricity, cable, phone, insurance, local service providers, etc—the important recurring things). Is there a term other than "bills" or "services" that encompasses all these things?

I'm trying to avoid the term "bills" and any synonyms. I'm looking for something closer to "services" but something that emphasizes their importance and recurrence (if possible). Because the emails I receive will be more than just bills—could be anything that those companies are trying to communicate to me. They could be marketing, newsletters, service updates. Even my doctor's communications could be thrown into the mix.

Comment: Maybe you could just call them your "business" emails, as opposed to "personal" emails with friends.

Comment: How about Utility correspondence.

Comment: Providers or Service Providers, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

These companies  could be all put under the umbrella term of "suppliers" (of good and services).

As defined under the norm ISO-9000*2000***10(E) and quoted by the [BtB](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=fournisseur&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0)

> Supplier:  producer, distributor, retailer or vendor of a product or provider of a service or information

Comment: I don't exactly think of my doctor or insurance as suppliers, though I suppose that's true in the technical sense.

Comment: They are providers/suppliers of services. You'll find them put under the tertiary sector in Economy. It might feel a bit weird, but ithey are under the same umbrella  as dancers, travel agents, priests, prostitutes, philosophers or plumbers...

Answer (score 1):

When looking at US accounting plan, you find the 3 different sections:

> *CONTRACTUAL SERVICES*: Includes expenditures for communication services, employee development services, health services, management
>   and informational services, repair and maintenance services, support
>   services, technical services, and transportation services.
>
> *CONTINUOUS CHARGES*: Includes expenditures for insurance fixed assets,insurance operations, capital, and operating lease payments,
>   installment purchases and service charges.
>
> *SERVICE CHARGES*: Includes expenditures for agency service charges, electrical service charges, refuse service charges, and water and
>   sewer service charges.

The 3 above services may perhaps be merged in **outside services** or **external services**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean 'Invoice'? It does come close to what you are looking for. It is synonymous with 'bill, and includes all services and goods.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the term "bill" and any synonyms, because the emails will not be only bills/invoices, but anything that those companies are trying to communicate to me.

Answer (score 0):

What about **documents**?

> a. A written or printed paper that bears the original, official, or legal form of something and can be used to furnish decisive evidence or information.
>   b. Something, such as a recording or a photograph, that can be used to furnish evidence or information.
>   c. A writing that contains information.
>   d. Computers A piece of work created with an application, as with a word processor.
>   e. Computers A computer file that is not an executable file and contains data for use by applications.

Perhaps that doesn't communicate their importance effectively enough, but in my mind it fits the variety of files you'll be receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "Continuous Services", to separate it from one-time charges which, I assume, are not included.